# Django form with formset between three models

Tags: django, django-forms, inline-formset

I have three models: `Experiment, Label and LabelMappings` while LabelMappings is connecting Devices with Labels. I want to create ExperimentForm but don't know how to add Label field to it using inline formset. I am using ClassBasedViews but couldn't figure out how to save Labels and build this relationship in backend

```
class Experiment(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    comment = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

class Label(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

class LabelMappings(models.Model):
    experiment = models.OneToOneField(Device, models.DO_NOTHING)
    label = models.ForeignKey(Location, models.DO_NOTHING)
```

I thought about somethinglike

```
LabelMappingFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Experiment,
                                        LabelMapping,
                                        form=LabelMappingForm,
                                        extra=1
                                        )



LabelFormSet = inlineformset_factory(LabelMappingForm,
                                        Label,
                                        form=LabelForm,
                                        extra=1
                                        )

but i didn't work out.
```